# How to pass data to another bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, clean-architecture

I have a login block, if the login data is successful, I need the OTP verification request, I need the successful login data to request the verification block. how do i get the data in the verification block?? by implementing a clean architecture

Answer (score 0):

Navigate with named routes and pass it as an argument, put it inside the widget constructor or wrap your MaterialApp with your Bloc to access the instance globally.

You could also work with singletons, service locators, etc. This may also help you https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

Comment: I want the data to be sent directly to the bloc not to the ui section first. Can it ?

Comment: Then you will have to pack your Bloc via the MaterialApp or otherwise make your data globally available. But I honestly don't see an anti pattern to pass your data in the BlocListener when navigating.